# Finding String in a list of text files in a directory Java ..want to locate line number.

Tags: java, parsing, line, reader

Hi I am trying to add a functionality where I can also keep track of the line number of the string that is found. Not sure where and how to implement this in the following code. Keep in mind the files that I am looking into are 50mb in size.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class scanFiles {
    private static void scanFiles(String folderPath, String searchString) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        File folder = new File(folderPath);

        if (folder.isDirectory()) {
            for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (!file.isDirectory()) {
                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String content = "";
                    try {
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        String line = br.readLine();

                        while (line != null) {
                            sb.append(line);
                            sb.append(System.lineSeparator());
                            line = br.readLine();
                        }
                        content = sb.toString();


                    } finally {
                        br.close();
                    }
                    if (content.contains(searchString)) {
                        System.out.println("File " + file.getName() + " contains searchString " + searchString + "!");
                    }

                }
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not a Directory!");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
        scanFiles(new File("C://Users//FarmaniA//Documents//COB NAK Messages").getAbsolutePath(),"15:09:07,803");

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the text as you loop over each line of the file while reading. Keep a record of the line numbers where the String is found. For example:

```
List<Integer> lineNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
int lineNumber = 0;
while ( line != null ){
    lineNumber++;
    if ( line.indexOf(searchString) != -1 ){
        lineNumbers.add(lineNumber);
    }
    line = br.readLine();
}
if ( lineNumbers.size() > 0 ){
    //do something with them
}
```

Depending upon context, you may also wish to do a case insensitive search by changing the search String and each line to a particular case (uppercase/lowercase).